# Take Media items by id in foreach - umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, media, umbraco

as I wrote in title I have problem with take Media in foreach.

This is my code:

```
@foreach (var item in @Model.Children.Where("Visible").OrderBy("UpdateDate"))
    {
        @{
            var link = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media.Media(item.MediaID).Children.FirstOrDefault().getProperty("umbracoFile").Value;
        }
        <div class="galleryListItem" style="background-image: url('/imageGen.ashx?image=@link&width=273&height=161');">
            <a href="@item.Url" class="link"></a>
            <div class="contentGalleryList">
                <div class="highlightGalleryList">@item.Name</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

and this line:

```
@link = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media.Media(item.MediaID).FirstOrDefault().getProperty("umbracoFile").Value;
```

give me this error:

```
Error loading MacroEngine script (file: GalleryList.cshtml);
```

What can I do to that start work? Maybe it's some better solve of this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have edited the orginal post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. The problem was that I have open code section in other code section.

Working code:

```
@foreach (var item in @Model.Children.Where("Visible").OrderBy("UpdateDate"))
{
    var link = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media.Media(item.MediaID).Children.FirstOrDefault().getProperty("umbracoFile").Value;

    <div class="galleryListItem" style="background-image: url('/imageGen.ashx?image=@link&width=273&height=161');">
        <a href="@item.Url" class="link"></a>
        <div class="contentGalleryList">
            <div class="highlightGalleryList">@item.Name</div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: " I have open code section in other code section" what does that mean??

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work for you: (I'm not 100% sure what you code is trying to do, I've assumed the item.MediaID contains the id of a media item)

```
@foreach (var item in @Model.Children.Where("Visible").OrderBy("UpdateDate"))
{
    var media = Library.MediaById(item.MediaID);

       <div class="galleryListItem" style="background-image: url('/imageGen.ashx?image=@media.Url&width=273&height=161');">
        <a href="@item.Url" class="link"></a>
        <div class="contentGalleryList">
            <div class="highlightGalleryList">@item.Name</div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

If you need more info of how to do things in Razor in Umbraco download the invaluable [umbraco DynamicNode razor cheatsheet](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/razor-dynamicnode-cheat-sheet)

There's also lots of great information on the [our.umbraco.org wiki](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/code-snippets/razor-snippets)

Comment: Hi, I'm not if I use it correct but at first I add @using umbraco.MacroEngines.Library; but it isn't help. Next I change var media = umbraco.MacroEngines.Library.MediaById(item.MediaID); because I have `"The name 'Liblary' does not exist in the current context`. And then i have error : `The type of namespace name 'MediaById' does not exist in the namespace 'umbraco.MacroEnginesLiblary'`. Do you know how can I solve it?